# Setting up Global sessions by using Passport Consumer strategy

Tags: node.js, session, express, authentication, passport.js

I need some help with setting up Passport Consumer Strategy and integrating it into "locals" (Right now, we have the local strategy working just fine). We have tried several approaches but with no luck on it working 100%. The below code is not the complete code, we have taken out some of it so this post doesn't get too long. Any help with this would greatly be appreciate. There could be compensation as well if someone can get us over this hurdle.

So one question is, if the user is authenticated by the consumer key and secret, how does Passport store the session variables so they are used throughout the site?

Second question, how do we handle the user after it passes the authentication process?

1. Both local and consumer need to be working.
2. Consumer key and secret using a POST by a Provider <- I can show some of the post if needed.
3. This needs to be OAuth1 Only, as of right now, OAuth2 isn't an option.
4. This is for a single sign-on authentication.
5. I can supply a consumer session output if needed.

Ultimately, we would like the local strategy and the consumer strategy working with the same "locals" global variables. As far as I can tell, we can authenticate the consumer, retrieve the user from our DB, create a session and can tell if user is "ensureAuthenticated".

Here is what we have working right now.

Local strategy is authenticating correctly.

**We render the pages with these local variables:**
"Omitted most of the code to save time."

```
//=================================================================
// The Authentication Module will bind to POST /login route
//=================================================================
authentication.initLocalStrategyRoutes(app);
passport.authenticate('local', {successReturnToOrRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login'});

...
function renderPage(req, res, pageName, pageTitle){
res.render(pageName, {
pageName: pageTitle,
username: req.user ? req.user.username : '',
...
```

Consumer strategy is authenticating by a POST request from a "Provider"

We have tried adding the Consumer strategy to the authentication.

server.js

```
//=================================================================
// The Authentication Module will bind to POST /login route
//=================================================================
authentication.initLocalStrategyRoutes(app);
ADDED -> authentication.initConsumerStrategyRoutes(app);
passport.authenticate('local', {successReturnToOrRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login'});
 ADDED -> passport.authenticate('consumer', {successReturnToOrRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login'});
```

authentication.js (omitted code)

```
module.exports = function(siteConfig, defaultRedirectPage, server, sessionStore, log) {
var passport = require('passport')
```

...

```
    , ConsumerStrategy = require('passport-http-oauth').ConsumerStrategy
    , TokenStrategy = require('passport-http-oauth').TokenStrategy
    , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

    var auth = {};
    var authenticationRedirects = { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' };

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {done(null, user);});
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {done(null, obj);});
auth.authenticate = function(email, password, callback) {
    email = email.toLowerCase();
    userController.findUserByUsernameWithPermissions(email,
        function(err, user) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            if (!user) return callback(null, null, 'Incorrect username.');
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password_hash, function(err, res) {
            if(err){return callback(err);
            } else if (!res) {return callback(null, null, 'Incorrect password.');
            } else {if (user.account_state>0) {callback(null, user);} else {return callback(null, null, '/reset?rand='+user._id);}}
            });
    }
);
}
auth.initLocalStrategyRoutes = function(app){
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(auth.authenticate));
    app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (!user) return res.send({success: false, message: info});
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                res.send(req.user);
            });
        }) (req, res, next);
    });
}
auth.initConsumerStrategyRoutes = function(app){
    // passport.use(new LocalStrategy(auth.authenticate));
    console.log('app: ', app)
    passport.use('consumer', new ConsumerStrategy(
      function(key, done) { console.log('starting ConsumerStrategy');

        dbConsumerKey.findByConsumerKey({consumerKey: key}, function(err, consumerKey) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }

          if (!consumerKey) {
            var errCode = dbError.find({name:'no_resource_link_id'}, function(err, errorCodes) {
              console.log('statusText: ', errorCodes[0]["statusText"]);
              return errorCodes[0]["statusText"];
            });
            return done(null, errCode);
          } else {
            if (!consumerKey[0]["consumerKey"]) { return done(err); }
            if (!consumerKey[0]["consumerSecret"]) { return done(err); }
            // return done(null, consumerKey[0]["consumerKey"], consumerKey[0]["consumerSecret"]);
            return done(null, consumerKey[0], consumerKey[0]["consumerSecret"]);
          }

        });
      },
      function(requestToken, done) {
        dbRequestTokens.find(requestToken, function(err, token) {
                console.log('inside requestToken');
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          var info = { verifier: token.verifier,
            clientID: token.clientID,
            userID: token.userID,
            approved: token.approved
          }
          done(null, token.secret, info);
        });
      },
      function(timestamp, nonce, done) {
        done(null, true)
      }
    ));
};

auth.initTokenStrategyRoutes = function(app){}
auth.addUser = function(username, email, password, callback){auth.authenticate(username, "pass", callback);}

return auth;
```

};

The authentication.js strategy does validate the consumer key and secret. but it doesn't create the session variable we are wanting. We would like the consumer strategy code to be in the authentication.js file.

---

Now here is another approach, we created a separate files called consumerkey.js

This direction works to a point. We can output the passport session either on the screen or on the command line.

```
var passport = require('passport')

exports.launchLti = [
    passport.authenticate('consumer', { session: false/true [tried both] }),
    function(req, res) {    

        db.findByStudentUserId({lis_person_contact_email_primary: 
        req.body.lis_person_contact_email_primary}, function(err, user) {
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
               req.user.username = user[0].lis_person_contact_email_primary;
        ...

      // req.session.save(function(){
      // res.redirect('/classes');
        res.redirect(200,'/');            
      // });
    });
  })
  // res.render('launch', {launch:  launch});
}
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing some of my code structure.

```
    app.pst('/launch/lti/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('consumer', {failureRedirect: '/login'}),
      dbConsumerKey.findByStudentUserId({}, 
        function(err, user) {
            if (err) console.log(err, user);
              req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) return err;
                ADDED -> req.session.valid = true;
                ADDED -> res.redirect('/');        
              });
          }
        });
  });
```

and modifying the render page function to adapt to the incoming information.

```
function renderPage(req, res, pageName, pageTitle){
...
this is where the locals are created
...
```

this allowed me to use my current local strategy as is and adding a totally different strategy route but making the session correctly.